# Tap on a UITableViewCell's custom button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to write a UITest that involves tapping on a button within a UITableViewCell.

[image]

When I try to record my tap actions when tapping on the cell, XCode generates the line:

```
[[[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].tables childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther] elementBoundByIndex:1].otherElements[@"Problems"] tap];
```

When played back, this results in the same action as tapping on the cell itself, which is not what I want.

Is there a way I can make it specifically press on the button?

Answer (score 3):

Set the accessibility identifier on the custom button. Then you can access it directly under test.

Application Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.accessoryView = CustomButton()
    cell.accessoryView.accessibilityIdentifier = "New Problem \(indexPath.row)"
}
```

Test Code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.buttons["New Problem 42"].tap()
```

Comment: I have multiple instances of the button on the screen. Would this still work?